# Rounded Corners of Carousel Images with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5, border-radius

Only the corners on the left side of the carousel images are rounded, and during the sliding animation those corners also become pointed again.

[image: Screenshot of carousel image while static, displaying both rounded and pointed corners.]

```css
#carouselCoulumn1Neutral {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

#carouselAboutNeutral {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#carouselImagesNeutral {
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-7" id="carouselCoulumn1Neutral">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" id="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <!-- <img src="Images/LianaMikah1.jpg" alt="LianaMikah1" id="carouselImagesNeutral"> -->
          <div style="background-color:pink;" id="carouselImagesNeutral">
        <p>Pink</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <!-- <img src="Images/LianaMikah7.jpg" alt="LianaMikah7" id="carouselImagesNeutral"> -->
          <div style="background-color:blue;" id="carouselImagesNeutral">
        <p>Blue</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <!-- <img src="Images/LianaMikah8.jpg" alt="LianaMikah8" id="carouselImagesNeutral"> -->
          <div style="background-color:green;" id="carouselImagesNeutral">
        <p>Green</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="col-sm-4" id="carouselCoulumn2Neutral">
    <div id="carouselAboutNeutral">
      <h3>About Carousel</h3>
      <p>Something about the carousel</p>
    </div>
  </div> -->

</div>
```

Ideally, I would like for the corners to be consistently rounded. I am unsure of how to achieve this.

Edited: After adding the code snippet I have found that all four corners of the div are rounded, however, the corners still become pointed during the sliding animation.

Comment: @LinDu No. Create a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: That said, looks like adding `rounded` class to `.carousel-inner` element works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in my comment, simply add the `rounded` class to the element with the `carousel-inner` class.

With Bootstrap 5, you have 5 different sizes of rounded corners that are [pre-defined](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/borders/#radius): `rounded-1`, `rounded-2`, etc.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="p-3">
  <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner rounded-5">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```